# undetected-chromedriver dont work with error TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, bots, executable-path

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()                      

driver.get("https://www.google.ru/")
```

Nothing happens, i just see this mistake, please tell me what can I do.

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe they changed something in `selenium` (or in `webdriver`) and you need newer `undetected_chromedriver`. OR maybe you have too new `undetected_chromedriver` and you need newer `selenium` (or you need older `undetected_chromedriver`)